# wordpress: media library issue with polylang plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a website with Wordpress, where i'm using the Polylang plugin to make content for multiple different languages.

I'm using Polylang for two languages: Dutch(primary) and English(secondary). When I upload images in Dutch pages, all is well. But when I create an English page, and want to add an image that is already been uploaded, the image library is empty. Anyone got an idea how to get them to appear there?

Thanks!

Comment: hello i have same problem. Did you resolved this question?

Answer (score 17):

I found the solution.

It is default for the Polylang plugin to enable multilingual support for media. This should be turned off. You can do this by unchecking the **'Activate languages and translations for media'** option, in the settings area of the Polylang plugin.

Comment: Although this solves the issue of which media shows up in the library, is there any way to keep the Caption / Alt text assigned per-language?

Comment: @chamberlainpi I'm glad I'm not the only one asking that very same question... more than six years later :-)

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn haha yeah, well in this day and age, six years passes by almost like a minute! lol