# media library doesn't display all images in multiple language wordpress

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I have use `Polylang` plugin which allows me to create posts in multiple language switch.

while i create post in English it will show all images and files in media library but when i switch post to another language it doesn't display media library.

any one knew about this. then help me to figured out

Comment: reganrate your thumbnail

Comment: Did you read https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/polylang  as I see half a dozen posts that give me the impression they have a bug, possibly with wp 4.5+

Comment: Thanks "Yezzz" i couldn't found the expected post on url you post but i found solution on url "https://wordpress.org/support/topic/polylang-makes-media-vanish-in-library". Languages > Settings tab > Media: uncheck and display all media image on other language also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is default for the Polylang plugin to enable multilingual support for media. This should be turned off. You can do this by unchecking the **'Activate languages and translations for media'** option, in the settings area of the Polylang plugin.

<sup>([wordpress: media library issue with polylang plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753339/wordpress-media-library-issue-with-polylang-plugin))</sup>

Comment: With a bit more rep, [you will be able to flag duplicate questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Until then, posting links, or simple copy-pastes, as answers is not really ideal, and they will generally be deleted. Or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.